# How to create an add method, that gets an argument, a reference to another object and then adds that object's value to the receiver's?

Tags: java, class, oop

```
class Money{
    private int cents;
    private int dollars;
    public Money(){
        this.cents=0;
    }
    public Money(Scanner sc){
        String token=sc.next();
        int dot=token.indexOf(".");
        this.cents=Integer.parseInt(token.substring(dot+1));
        this.dollars=Integer.parseInt(token.substring(1,dot));
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "$"+dollars+"."+cents;
    }
    public boolean equals(Money other){
        if(!(other instanceof Money)){
            return false;
        }
        return this.dollars==other.dollars && this.cents==other.cents;
    }
    public Money add(Money other){
        return 
    }
}
```

Here is my class, I can't seem to figure out how to create the add method that adds an object's value to the receiver's. Any tips or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll need getters for your fields, and then it's a simple matter of using them and the `+=` operator (or the assignment and addition operators separately) to update the values of your fields. If you want to get fancy you can include a check for when the value of `cents` goes over 100 to convert it to dollars, add it to the `dollars` field and keep the remainder as the value of the `cents` field.

Comment: Your `equals` method doesn’t do what you think it does. Also `add` should likely be `void` if it mutates `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution assuming that the `cents` value should always be kept within `[0, 100] range` in any instance of `Money`:

```java
public Money add(Money other) {
    if (null != other) {
        this.cents += other.cents;
        if (this.cents >= 100) {
            this.cents %= 100;
            this.dollars++;
        }
        this.dollars += other.dollars;
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Assumes that the `other` `Money` always has a valid quantity of cents.